# Numpy slice with preserving dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Why does python not preserve the dimensions on a conditioned slice ?

If I do the following, an array with only one dimension is the result.

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(11,300) # .shape = (11,300)                 
arr2 = np.random.rand(11,300) # .shape = (11,300) 
cond = arr2 > 0.5 # .shape = (11,300)  

arr3 = arr1[cond] # .shape = (1649,)
```

What is the logic behind that slice, that returns an 1d array? 
And what's the best practice to get an `(11,300)` array returned ?

Comment: In order to keep the same shape you have to have something in the place of the values that don't fit the condition.  Do you want to fill them with `Nan` :  `arr1[~cond] = np.nan`   ?

Comment: `arr1[cond]` says to only take some elements of `arr1`, specifically those matching True entries of `cond`. Why are *you* expecting an output with a number of elements equal to *all* the elements of `arr1`?

Comment: I expected an output with same shape und the False values filled with nan or empty. But Bunji's answer is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

> Unlike in the case of integer index arrays, in the boolean case, the result is a 1-D array containing all the elements in the indexed array corresponding to all the true elements in the boolean array.

It expands on the case where `arr1` has more dimensions than the mask.  But the basic point is there's logically nothing else it can return.

Look at `cond` (maybe for a smaller case).  How else do you map the `True` values on to a (11,300) array?

Have you looked at `masked arrays`?  That keeps the original shape, replacing the 'masked' values with '--' (in the display).

---

```
In [284]: arr1 =np.random.randint(0,10,(4,5))
In [285]: arr1
Out[285]: 
array([[4, 6, 5, 8, 8],
       [4, 0, 4, 8, 1],
       [3, 9, 0, 3, 2],
       [8, 8, 7, 5, 7]])
In [286]: mask = arr1<4
In [287]: mask
Out[287]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [288]: arr1[mask]
Out[288]: array([0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2])
In [289]: arrM=np.ma.MaskedArray(arr1,~mask)
In [290]: arrM
Out[290]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- -- --]
 [-- 0 -- -- 1]
 [3 -- 0 3 2]
 [-- -- -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: Such a solution like an masked array is the thing i was looking for. Didnt know that numpy provide such mask. Thank you !